# Interactive Input in AWX/ Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have a requirement where I need to get the inputs from the user when the playbook is being executed. I used "pause" module and hence was able to get the input from the user during runtime of the playbook which went well on Ansible CLI.

But, when the same playbook was executed on AWX/Ansible Tower, the execution was paused waiting for the input from the user. But, there is no way to pass the input during run-time.

Can I get some help on how to give input on AWX in such case ? If it is not possible, please let me know the alternatives, if any.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Short answer: you can't, use a survey instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your

> *requirement where I need to get the inputs from the user when the playbook is being executed.*

this will not be possible during playbook execution. Neither via [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) module with parameter `prompt`, nor via [Interactive input: prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) (`vars_prompt`).

> *the execution was paused waiting for the input from the user. But, there is no way to pass the input during run-time.*

Right, as this is the expected behavior. According Ansible Tower [Best Pratices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/best_practices.html)

> *Playbooks should not use the `vars_prompt` feature, as Tower does not interactively allow for `vars_prompt` questions. If you must use `vars_prompt`, refer to and make use of the [Surveys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#surveys) functionality of Tower.*

Comment: Is there any way in survey to use dynamic content (such as listing the files in a particular directory as options in multiple choice type questions).. etc ??

Comment: Since the Survey is executed / running on the Control Node, whereby listing files in a directory could be a task on a Remote Node during execution time and therefore such information is unknown on Control Node, there is no way for such behavior.